# iOS 8 iPhone 6/6 Plus display issue

Tags: xcode, storyboard, ios8

I've recently tried to convert my App for use with iOS 8, with the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus.

Anyone got any idea what could cause the following issue?

[image]  [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
mapView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

before adding the mapView as a subview, should fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

mapView.frame = self.view.bounds will work. However I recommend adding constraints to the whole view and all it's subviews. The view controller will be more dynamic when dealing with different screen sizes.